# Get status from ASyncResult

Tags: java, junit, playframework-2.0, functional-testing

Is there anyway that I can extract the `status` from an `AsyncResult`?  I am writing a functional test to make sure that all `routes` work and need to output the `status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the status (but not return it) in with the [transform](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.AsyncResult) method :

```
Async {
  concurrent.future(Ok("ok"))
} transform { result =>
  println(result.header.status)
  result
}
```